# Python - Join two dataframes based on closest date match and additional column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I need to join on two columns, one of which is a date column. However, the dates do not match as shown in below example. I have seen people on other posts using merge_of for similar examples however that will not work here I believe as I also need to join on another non-date column(pty).I would like to output the closest alert_dt to the inv_dt that is before or the same as the inv_dt. First post for me so please let me know if anything is unclear.

DataFrame A:

```
|alert_dt|pty|
|--------|---|
| 01/06/2020|A|
| 08/06/2020|A|
| 12/06/2020|A|
| 27/06/2020|A|
| 12/06/2020|B|
| 15/07/2020|B|
```

DataFrame B:

```
|inv_dt     | pty|
|-----------|----|
| 07/06/2020| A  |
| 14/06/2020| A  |
| 27/06/2020| A  |
| 12/07/2020| B  |
| 15/08/2020| B  |
```

Desired Output:

```
|inv_dt|closest_alert_dt_before_inv_dt|pty|
|------|--------|---|
|07/06/2020| 01/06/2020|A|
|14/06/2020| 08/06/2020|A|
|27/06/2020| 27/06/2020|A|
|12/07/2020|12/06/2020|B|
|15/08/2020|15/07/2020|B|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My output is a bit different in [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) method:

```
df1['alert_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['alert_dt'], dayfirst=True)
df2['inv_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['inv_dt'], dayfirst=True)


df = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('inv_dt'), 
                   df1.sort_values('alert_dt'), 
                   left_on='inv_dt', 
                   right_on='alert_dt', 
                   by='pty')
print (df)
      inv_dt pty   alert_dt
0 2020-06-07   A 2020-06-01
1 2020-06-14   A 2020-06-12
2 2020-06-27   A 2020-06-27
3 2020-07-12   B 2020-06-12
4 2020-08-15   B 2020-07-15
```

Comment: Fantastic, this did the job. Hadn't seen answer on here using the by argument which was the key. Thank you!